# Change Loading Screen

Tags: android, splash-screen

I've created an android app, and everything works fine, but when you first hit the icon to launch the app it flashes white with the title bar for a second or two before loading the full interface.

I have a previous app the just flashes black for a second or two before launching, without the title bar but I can't seem to find what is different in the setup/code that makes it do that.

After the app loads I'm removing the title bar with the following line in `onCreate`

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.
In your Manifest activity include android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar"

```
   <activity
        android:name=".MainScreen"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Comment: Adding that line was the right solution but it needed to be just `Theme.NoTitleBar` to make it black

Answer (score 1):

Add the below line in your `Manifest` file for the `splashaActivity`,

```
<activity android:name="splashActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" />
```

Hope this will solve your problem.